# Issue adding third-party jars to hadoop job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hdfs

I am trying to add third-party jars to a hadoop job. I am adding each jar using the `DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath` method. I can see that the `mapred.job.classpath.files` is properly populated in the job xml file.

-libjars does not work for me either (most likely because we are not using toolrunner)

Any suggestions, what could be wrong?

Comment: Are the jars you are adding already in HDFS, or local to your job client?

Comment: And you should really use ToolRunner where you can

Answer (score 0):

Add the Jar in HADOOP_CLASSPATH

```
    vi $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
```

Add last line

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/root/hadoop/extrajars/java-json.jar:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH
```

"/root/hadoop/extrajars/java-json.jar" is path on linux box itself and not on HDFS

Restart the hadoop

Command

```
hadoop classpath
```

Should show the jar in classpath

Now run MR job as usual

```
hadoop jar <MR-program jar> <MR Program class> <input dir> <output dir>
```

It will use the file from as expected.